# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused (long period after use Browser() function)

Tags: python, selenium, web-applications, splinter

I am trying to do the tutorial at : https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

And the error message are:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

and I am stuck where I try to execute

```
browser = Browser()
```

there are a lot of things inside geckodriver.log, I will just give the top one and the bottom one

top:

```
1507234197323   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.0
1507234197399   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:53887
1507234198443   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/var/folders/1_/pyjxm9nn15qdx2hxhpczsb6h0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.wOgxwnTgLlj0"
```

bottom :

```
1507235042100   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /private/var/folders/1_/pyjxm9nn15qdx2hxhpczsb6h0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/tmpaddon
1507235043389   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1507235043392   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /private/var/folders/1_/pyjxm9nn15qdx2hxhpczsb6h0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/tmpaddon
```

Any idea how to solve this? I also would like to use google chrome instead of Mozilla Firefox. please help me

P.S: I tried to check another threat which have similar problem, but our geckodriver log different.

Comment: The error is consistent? If so please provide complete log on https://pastebin.com link

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is the link from pastebin.com : https://pastebin.com/cgs6Mbp9